Comparing a column value to a constant from CASE WHEN fails
MySQL 8.0.40
The following code works exactly as intended.  I create two CTE's, each returning two columns.
I then compare the value of the Jan 2022 column to the Jan 2021 column.  If Jan 2022 is greater,
create a new column named "2022_is_greater" and fill with a 1, else 0.
However, if I try to filter on the newly created "2022_is_greater" column, it doesn't work.
ON
 Pr_2021 = Pr_2022
WHERE
 '2022_is_greater' = 1;

appended to the end results in zero rows returned (should be 18).
For grins I also tried:
ON
 Pr_2021 = Pr_2022
WHERE
 '2022_is_greater' > x;

where 'x' is any integer, 0 or larger, it returns all 18 rows. (As it turns out, in every row the Jan 2022
value is larger).  But this should return zero rows for any value of x greater than 0.
I am also getting this when I add the comparison via the WHERE clause:
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '2022_is_greater'
I looked it up but I don't understand why I am getting this.  I am simply checking if the value in the column is 1 or not.  I am not performing a string comparison.
Correctly functioning full query without the WHERE clause at the very end:
WITH Jan2021 AS (
    SELECT
     SUM(s.Amount) as SUM_Jan_2021,
     pr.Product as Pr_2021
    FROM
     sales AS s
    INNER JOIN
     products AS pr
    ON
     pr.PID = s.PID 
      AND DATE(s.SaleDate) BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' AND pr.Category != 'Other'
    GROUP BY
     pr.Product
    ORDER BY
     SUM_Jan_2021 DESC
),
Jan2022 AS (
    SELECT
     SUM(s.Amount) as SUM_Jan_2022,
     pr.Product as Pr_2022
    FROM
     sales AS s
    INNER JOIN
     products AS pr
    ON
     pr.PID = s.PID 
      AND DATE(s.SaleDate) BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-31' AND pr.Category != 'Other'
    GROUP BY
     pr.Product
    ORDER BY
     SUM_Jan_2022 DESC
)
SELECT
 SUM_Jan_2021,
 SUM_Jan_2022,
 Pr_2021,
 Pr_2022,
 CASE WHEN SUM_Jan_2022 > SUM_Jan_2021 THEN 1
      ELSE 0
 END AS "2022_is_greater"
FROM
 Jan2021 AS J21
INNER JOIN
 Jan2022 AS J22
ON
 Pr_2021 = Pr_2022;



Please share some input data to help reproducing this

This question is similar to: Filtering on an alias in mysql. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You could make a further CTE and use it as base
WITH Jan2021 AS (
    SELECT
     SUM(s.Amount) as SUM_Jan_2021,
     pr.Product as Pr_2021
    FROM
     sales AS s
    INNER JOIN
     products AS pr
    ON
     pr.PID = s.PID 
      AND DATE(s.SaleDate) BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' AND pr.Category != 'Other'
    GROUP BY
     pr.Product
    ORDER BY
     SUM_Jan_2021 DESC
),
Jan2022 AS (
    SELECT
     SUM(s.Amount) as SUM_Jan_2022,
     pr.Product as Pr_2022
    FROM
     sales AS s
    INNER JOIN
     products AS pr
    ON
     pr.PID = s.PID 
      AND DATE(s.SaleDate) BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-31' AND pr.Category != 'Other'
    GROUP BY
     pr.Product
    ORDER BY
     SUM_Jan_2022 DESC
), S_UM  as (
SELECT
 SUM_Jan_2021,
 SUM_Jan_2022,
 Pr_2021,
 Pr_2022,
 CASE WHEN SUM_Jan_2022 > SUM_Jan_2021 THEN 1
      ELSE 0
 END AS "2022_is_greater"
FROM
 Jan2021 AS J21
INNER JOIN
 Jan2022 AS J22
ON
 Pr_2021 = Pr_2022)
SELECT
 SUM_Jan_2021,
 SUM_Jan_2022,
 Pr_2021,
 Pr_2022
 FROM
 S_UM
 WHERE 2022_is_greater = 1;

Or you can use HAVING
WITH Jan2021 AS (
    SELECT
     SUM(s.Amount) as SUM_Jan_2021,
     pr.Product as Pr_2021
    FROM
     sales AS s
    INNER JOIN
     products AS pr
    ON
     pr.PID = s.PID 
      AND DATE(s.SaleDate) BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' AND pr.Category != 'Other'
    GROUP BY
     pr.Product
    ORDER BY
     SUM_Jan_2021 DESC
),
Jan2022 AS (
    SELECT
     SUM(s.Amount) as SUM_Jan_2022,
     pr.Product as Pr_2022
    FROM
     sales AS s
    INNER JOIN
     products AS pr
    ON
     pr.PID = s.PID 
      AND DATE(s.SaleDate) BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-31' AND pr.Category != 'Other'
    GROUP BY
     pr.Product
    ORDER BY
     SUM_Jan_2022 DESC
)
SELECT
 SUM_Jan_2021,
 SUM_Jan_2022,
 Pr_2021,
 Pr_2022,
 CASE WHEN SUM_Jan_2022 > SUM_Jan_2021 THEN 1
      ELSE 0
 END AS "2022_is_greater"
FROM
 Jan2021 AS J21
INNER JOIN
 Jan2022 AS J22
ON
 Pr_2021 = Pr_2022
 HAVING  2022_is_greater = 1;


@Marks:   or you could use the complete CASE WHEN....END in the WHERE-clause, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/Usu2OaoZ
